# Possibly unhandled rejection: - When trying to pass data from angularJS to spring MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

This error is testing me a lot. Can someone help what have I done wrong?

I have a script that holds the value of few parameters in JSON format.

```
var mpdApp = angular.module('mpdApp', ['ngAnimate',
    'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'
]);

mpdApp
    .controller(
        'mpdController',
        [
            '$scope',
            '$rootScope',
            '$http',
            '$window',

            function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $window) {
                $scope.doValidation = function() {

                    var mpdData = {
                        'mpdPolicyNumber': $scope.mpdPolicyNumber,
                        'mpdFirstName': $scope.mpdFirstName,
                        'mpdLastName': $scope.mpdLastName,
                        'mpdAddress': $scope.mpdAddress,
                        'mpdPhoneNumber': $scope.mpdPhoneNumber
                    };

                    console.log(mpdData);

                    $http({
                            'url': '/mpdValidate',
                            'method': 'POST',
                            'headers': {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            'params': mpdData
                        })
                        .then(
                            function(response) {
                                $rootScope.resultMpdData = response.data;
                            });
                };
            }
        ]);
```

When I try to pass this to my spring mvc controller via POST,

**spring mvc controller method**:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/mpdValidate", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<MPDValidationOutputVO> mpdValidate(@RequestParam("mpdPolicyNumber") String mpdPolicyNumber,
            @RequestParam("mpdFirstName") String mpdFirstName, @RequestParam("mpdLastName") String mpdLastName,
            @RequestParam("mpdAddress") String mpdAddress, @RequestParam("mpdPhoneNumber") String mpdPhoneNumber)
            throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        System.out.println("*************");
        MPDValidationInputVO mpdValidationInput = new MPDValidationInputVO();
        List<MPDValidationOutputVO> mpdValidationOutput = mpdValidationService.mpdValidate(mpdValidationInput);
        return mpdValidationOutput;
    }
```

I get this error.
[image: error]

**Console log**:

```
{mpdPolicyNumber: "werwer", mpdFirstName: "czxc", mpdLastName: "werwe", mpdAddress: "ghhdf", mpdPhoneNumber: "asaa"}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at your network tab, you're receiving a 404 error. You're probably posting to the wrong URL, check your ports, if you're hosting the applications separately they should have different ports.

Comment: My URL is the one specified in the mvc Luiz. And it is in the same application where the script is. Everything runs on the same port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this variation

```
$http({
        url: 'request-url',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'message' : message }
    })
```

As url is already a parameter ,you should not quote it in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

produces = "application/json" will only handle if Accept header is "application/json"

Too much parameter here in your method, only 1 parameter missing, it will cause 404.

You might want to add default value or required=false if parameter's not visible. it will help you to prevent the 404 error.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/mpdValidate", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<MPDValidationOutputVO> mpdValidate(@RequestParam("mpdPolicyNumber") String mpdPolicyNumber,
            @RequestParam("mpdFirstName") String mpdFirstName, @RequestParam("mpdLastName") String mpdLastName,
            @RequestParam("mpdAddress") String mpdAddress, @RequestParam("mpdPhoneNumber") String mpdPhoneNumber)
            throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        System.out.println("*************");
        MPDValidationInputVO mpdValidationInput = new MPDValidationInputVO();
        List<MPDValidationOutputVO> mpdValidationOutput = mpdValidationService.mpdValidate(mpdValidationInput);
        return mpdValidationOutput;
    }
```